# When using Raw Input for the keyboard, is there a way to access key remappings?

Tags: windows, winapi, keyboard, raw-input

By 'remapped' I mean by using the  Windows feature for automatically translating scan codes to other scan codes.  This is configured by tools like KeyTweak, or directly through editing a certain registry key.

If you use WM_KEYDOWN messages and friends, you get the correctly remapped keys.  The same goes for DirectInput.  But not so for Raw Input.  Is there a way to get the remapped keys?  I don't need the original scan codes or VK codes, just the remapped ones.

MSDN says that DirectInput when used for keyboard input is a wrapper for Raw Input.  But somehow DirectInput gets you the remapped keys, while Raw Input does not.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that DI reads the Scancode Map value from the registry when initialized and translates the key codes internally. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447) is some old, but still correct, documentation on the "Scancode Map" registry value.

Comment: Thanks, that seems likely.  Too much trouble for my needs, though.